# hadoop parallel tasks with one small file

Tags: hadoop, split, mapreduce, avro

I have a cluster of 3 nodes and some 40Mb avro file. I want to parallelize the job in order to take advantage of multi-core, because each line of the file is processed via the same long-running algo. I read about `NLineInputFormat` but I am wondering if setting the configuration

some_conf.set("mapred.max.split.size",some_value);

would make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. If you want to process your file of size 40 MB(assuming 64Mb block size) with more than 1 mapper there by utilizing your cluster, then set `mapred.max.split.size` to a value of your use which by default is Long.MAX_VALUE.

The split size is calculated by the formula

```
max(mapred.min.split.size, min(mapred.max.split.size, blocksize))
```

So in your case you will get(assuming you set your maxsplitsize to 15MB.

```
max(1 byte(by default),min(15MB,64MB))
```

Your split size would be set to 15MB.